# Is GAE compatible with Protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

The docs (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions) caution that GAE doesn't support the open sourced implementation of protocol buffers (https://code.google.com/p/protobuf). I can't find any other mention of what is supported.

Furthermore, it isn't clear to me, which implementation is compatible with the GCD (https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/proto) API.

If I pip install protobuf, then I get the following error from the python code generated from protoc:

> ImportError: No module named protobuf

I'm guessing this is because there is a "google" package on the system path provided by GAE that does not support protobuf? There are numerous hacks/workarounds (e.g., https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-gae-hack/).

Is there any official support for protobuf? Is anyone using PB reliably across different Google Cloud products (e.g., GAE, GCE, GCD)?

Thanks,

RB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use the open source protobuf library with app engine, but you have to merge the module paths so that the system 'google.appengine' module can be accessed alongside 'google.protobuf'. E.g., if you use pip to install protobuf in your project's lib/ directory, then the following code will merge the lib/google path with the system provided google path.

```
import os
lib = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib')
sys.path.insert(0, lib)

import google
google.__path__.append(os.path.join(lib, 'google'))
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about `module.__path__`! It's not every day I learn something like this.